# Blocking event handler

Tags: c#, npgsql

Having the following code:

```
var conn = new NpgsqlConnection("...");
conn.Open();
conn.Notification += (o, e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Received notification begin");
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
    Console.WriteLine("Received notification end");
};

using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("LISTEN query", conn))
{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

while (true)
{
    conn.Wait();
}
```

When I run it an trigger from the database 2 requests quickly the output is:

> Received notification begin
>
> Received notification end
>
> Received notification begin
>
> Received notification end

This shows that the 2 event only triggers after the 1st event ends.

In the event handler I need to run some code until the next event triggers:

```
var stream = Stream.CreateFilteredStream();
...
stream.StartStreamMatchingAllConditions(); // blocking
```

When the next event triggers I need to call `stream.StopStream()` (to end previous stream) before running same code in the handler.

The issue is that because `stream.StartStreamMatchingAllConditions()` is blocking, the next event does not trigger so it is not possible to stop the previous stream.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the request correctly, you want to be able to process the next notification before handling of the first notification is completed. This would imply that your event handler code was running in a separate thread from the one dispatching the events from Npgsql - that's not the case.

You can easily achieve this in your code, though, by running your handling code in a separate thread yourself:

```
conn.Notification += (o, e) =>
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Received notification begin");
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        Console.WriteLine("Received notification end");
    });
};
```